# How do i create a slideshow in bootstrap that keeps moving?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow, carousel

Here is an example of what i am looking for:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/InfiniteCSSSlideshow/

but without the hover effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:
but there are also hover effect

to see the slider in action go at last of the page

http://designshack.net/articles/css/infinitephotobanner/

Comment: exactly what i was looking for and it works a treat! Thanks! @Shakir Khan